# How to read presentationML and place the output on Active slide of powerpoint using c# VSTO

Tags: c#, .net, vsto

I want to store a **PresentaionML** in a string and insert the actual output of that PresentaionML on Active slide as a paragraph or something on a button click ,in powerpoint presentaion.
for e.g:

```
string s = "some tag of presentaionML like  <presentaionML> Hello world </presentaionML>"
```

using c# VSTO

Answer (score 0):

Only Word supports inserting Open Office XML in a file opened in the application interface. This isn't possible for PowerPoint (or Excel).

Comment: any alternative for this ? because presentaionML is the language for the presentaions that its use

Comment: You could probably use [tag:openxml] rather than [tag:vsto], but the file could not be open at the same time.